# Error connecting DB2 instance on IBM cloud

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I am trying to connect to DB2 instance on IBM Cloud using the below code:

`%sql ibm_db_sa://nlf36689:25s9wzjqm%40mtbz8z@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-12.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB`
[image]

I am getting a error as:

(ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: Exception('[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "169.44.98.106".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10060", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-30081')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Remove your credentials from your question.

Comment: This is a connection timeout. Verify that the remote Db2-instance is running (for example: try connecting to the same database with the web gui in your browser).  If it connects, then verify your MS-Windows workstation firewall has a rule to enable inbound/outbound traffic on port 50000 for tcp.